# MVC Asp.net - calling ActionResult that redirects to URL on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a simple `ActionResult` in `AccountController` that should redirect to a specific URL:

```
[Route("account/redirect")]
public ActionResult RedirectGoogle()
{
    return Redirect("https://google.com");
}
```

And I want to call the action in view using Razor like this:

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("RedirectGoogle","AccountController")"> Goto Google</a>
```

but when clicking the link, nothing happens and the action is not even called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to just write `href="https://google.com"`?

Comment: Anyway, check the source code of your page - does the href contain the link you expected? Next, check your Console and Network tools. What happens when you click the link? Any errors? Does the Network log show any kind of request? Have you tried stopping the debugger in the C# on the `return` line, to see if the action is being run? It's a bit unclear precisely what debugging steps you have taken so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove controller text in `Url.Action`, change to

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("RedirectGoogle","Account")"> Goto Google</a>
```